# Seeking a specific proof of endpoint boundedness of Riesz potential

Tags: reference-request, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, potential-theory

The Riesz potential is defined by

$$I_\alpha (f)(x) := c_{d, \alpha} \int_{\mathbb R^d} \frac{f(y)}{|x-y|^{d-\alpha}}
 \, dy.$$

Once $f\in L^{d/\alpha}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, then $I_\alpha f(x)\in BMO$. For this result, I need a specific proof.

Answer (score 1):

In [Reference request: Riesz potential $I_\alpha : L^{d/\alpha} \to \rm{BMO}$?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/204040/reference-request-riesz-potential-i-alpha-ld-alpha-to-rmbmo), Prof. Jean Van Schaftingen gave a specific proof of this result. The key estimate in his proof is 
$$
\int_{B_r} \int_{B_r}\Big\vert \frac{1}{\vert z - x\vert^{d - \alpha}} -  \frac{1}{\vert z - y\vert^{d - \alpha}} \Big\vert
\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y
\le \frac{C r^{2 d + 1}}{(r + \vert z \vert)^{d - \alpha + 1}},
$$
once this estimate is obtained, then we can use the Holder inequality to complete this proof.